# "Search for Usages" for Delphi 7?

Tags: delphi, delphi-7

Delphi XE+ has a "Search for Usages" option. Is there a similar option in Delphi 7 to find function/procedure callers? I either do a plain text search or place a breakpoint and see who the caller was in the Call Stack during run time. Both are time consuming and very inefficient.

Opening the app in Delphi XE and using "Search for Usages" doesn't work. The app doesn't compile.

Comment: Not ideal but you could rename the method and look at the generated compiler errors to find all callers *(those that can be resolved at compile time)*.

Comment: The "Search for Usages" function is not very reliable anyway. There are situations where it does not find a usage.

Comment: Lieven has it right: Renaming the method is the simplest way to find all uses. Unfortunately you have to rename all uses in turn to find the next use. And afterwards revert the changes. Alternatively you could use Find in Files (Did that exist in Delphi 7? I already used GExperts back then) or GExpert's Grep if the method name is sufficiently unique.

Comment: @Lieven Good idea. You can put it as an answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not ideal but alternatively you could

- Rename the method
- Compile
- Check the compiler errors to find all callers *(those that can be resolved at compile time)*.

As mentioned by [dummzeug](https://stackoverflow.com/users/49925/dummzeuch)

> Renaming the method is the simplest way to find all uses.
>   Unfortunately you have to rename all uses in turn to find the next
>   use. And afterwards revert the changes.

Answer (score 2):

There is no equivalent to [Search for Usages](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE5/en/Search_for_Usages_dialog_box) in Delphi 7.  That feature was first introduced in XE.

Even the [Find References](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE5/en/Find_References_Overview_(Delphi,_C%2B%2B)) feature was not introduced until Delphi 2005 (when Delphi switched to the Galileo IDE).

Answer (score 1):

There is an anlternate way of find the callers:

Use a debugger that can show the Call Stack (like [MadExcept](http://madshi.net/madExceptDescription.htm)) and make a "fake" exception in your function like this:

```
function WhereDoYouCallMe;
  begin
    raise Exception.Create('Called');
    ...
    ...
  end;
```

Now every time the function is called, you will get an error box where you can view the Stack and get where it called. You can continue the program or you can set your breakpoints and so on.

Comment: This is a completely inadequate substitute because it performs dynamic analysis rather than static analysis. The entire point of a static tool is to find all possible call paths.

Answer (score 1):

You can also mark the method 'deprecated' and you will get a list of usages in your compiler warnings.